# Macro for saving Excel column in Notepad

Tags: vba, excel

My range in Excel is as follows:

`Range("S15").Select`
`Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select`, and I have to save this range automatically in Notepad with a macro.

I have already this code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Step_6_test()

Dim FilePath As String
Dim CellData As String
Dim LastCol As Long
Dim LastRow As Long

LastCol = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column
LastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

CellData = ""
FilePath = Application.DefaultFilePath & "\auth.csv"

Open FilePath For Output As #2

For i = 1 To LastRow

    For j = 1 To LastCol
        If j = LastCol Then
            CellData = CellData + Trim(ActiveCell(i, j).Value)
        Else
            CellData = CellData + Trim(ActiveCell(i, j).Value) + ","
        End If
    Next j

    Write #2, CellData
    CellData = ""
Next i

Close #2
MsgBox ("Done")

End Sub
```

But this code is for saving it in a Excel text file, but I want to save my range in Notepad automatically. 
How can I Change the code for saving my range in notepad?

Comment: Why not use .txt rather than .csv in the file path?

Comment: I have to save it in notepad in txt format for my work

Comment: So change `auth.csv` to `auth.txt`.

Comment: You *are* saving the data as a simple text file (that is what a csv file is). If you want to have it with a .txt extension -- just do it. It is your code that is telling it to use .csv. Just change that to .txt.

Comment: Right-click on `auth.csv` and open it with Notepad?

Answer (score 1):

Following-up on @Limak comment, Just save the file as `.txt`.

Also, you have `CellData = CellData + Trim(ActiveCell(i, j).Value)`, but you are not advancing the `ActiveCell` in your loop (nore do you need to use `ActiveCell`). Instead you could use `CellData = CellData + Trim(Cells(i, j).Value)`.

**Full Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub Step_6_test()

Dim FilePath As String
Dim CellData As String
Dim LastCol As Long
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim i As Long, j As Long

LastCol = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column
LastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

CellData = ""
FilePath = Application.DefaultFilePath & "\auth.txt"

Open FilePath For Output As #2

For i = 1 To LastRow

    For j = 1 To LastCol
        If j = LastCol Then
            CellData = CellData + Trim(Cells(i, j).Value)
        Else
            CellData = CellData + Trim(Cells(i, j).Value) + ","
        End If
    Next j

    Write #2, CellData
    CellData = ""
Next i

Close #2
MsgBox ("Done")

End Sub
```

Comment: @Hakan Yilmaz to further explain what Shai was saying about not needing to use `ActiveCell` take a look at [this SO question and its answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros)